# Bookmarks Syncing across browswer

Tags: google-sync

I am using safari on Windows7 pc fairly ok,,,
I have recently taken a liking to Google Chrome as it works on my work PC also,,,
My Question is,,, is it possible to have my Bookmarks sync between Windows Safari and Goggle Chrome,,,
ive added the sync thing in Chrome and also some addin called xMarks,,, however i seem to have gotten a little mixed up with it all ,,,(as is usual with any syncing activities)